# How to insert xml python when multiple fields have the same name?

Tags: python, xml

I've been struggling to add some XML code within existing one to interact with a REST API with python.

Here is the code I came up with:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml_str = """<entry>
    <id>com.scur.type.string.1846</id>
    <title>Global Bobo</title>
    <type>com.string</type>
    <listType>string</listType>
    <link href="https://internalonly" rel="self"/>
    <content>
        <list version="1">
            <description>SmartL both sides of the entry</description>
            <content>
                <listEntry>
                    <entry>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</entry>
                    <description>description for aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</description>
                </listEntry>
                <listEntry>
                    <entry>bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</entry>
                    <description />
                </listEntry>
                <listEntry>
                    <entry>ADDEDVIAREST.COM</entry>
                    <description />
                </listEntry>
                <listEntry>
                    <entry>ADDEDVIA-PYTHON-REST.COM</entry>
                    <description />
                </listEntry>
            </content>
        </list>
    </content>
</entry>"""

# build the tree
tree = ET.fromstring(xml_str)

# create the file structure
data = ET.Element('listEntry')
entry = ET.SubElement(data, 'entry')
description = ET.SubElement(data, 'description')
entry.text = 'blabla.com'
description.text = 'weehaaw'

for row in tree.iterfind('.//content'):
    row.append(data)

print(ET.tostring(tree))
```

As you may notice, the output is not satisfactory, my created element is inserted in multiple places within the XML, I supposed that it's dur to the same field name inside the XML.

My goal would be to insert a new listentry with entry and description within the correct "content" (just below the other entries). Would there be any way to do that ?

I use python 2.7 if that is any help (company rule).

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the culprit:

```
for row in tree.iterfind('.//content'):
    row.append(data)
```

You were adding to every instance. You can remove this and just look for the second/inner `<content>` tag and use `ET.SubElement` there.

```
content = tree.findall('.//content')[1] # Just get the second instance.
data = ET.SubElement(content, 'listEntry')
entry = ET.SubElement(data, 'entry')
description = ET.SubElement(data, 'description')
entry.text = 'blabla.com'
description.text = 'weehaaw'
```

This should add `data` only to the inner instance.

```
<entry>
    <id>com.scur.type.string.1846</id>
    <title>Global Bobo</title>
    <type>com.string</type>
    <listType>string</listType>
    <link href="https://internalonly" rel="self" />
    <content>
        <list version="1">
            <description>SmartL both sides of the entry</description>
            <content>
                <listEntry>
                    <entry>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</entry>
                    <description>description for aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</description>
                </listEntry>
                <listEntry>
                    <entry>bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</entry>
                    <description />
                </listEntry>
                <listEntry>
                    <entry>ADDEDVIAREST.COM</entry>
                    <description />
                    </listEntry>
                    <listEntry>
                        <entry>ADDEDVIA-PYTHON-REST.COM</entry>
                        <description />
                    </listEntry>
                <listEntry>
                    <entry>blabla.com</entry>
                    <description>weehaaw</description>
                </listEntry>
            </content>
        </list>
    </content>
</entry>
```

Comment: thanks for the tips ! I still need to learn a lot about python. Are you missing one line to add properly the data within content though ?

Comment: @Galgu What do you mean? It's added there at the end of the inner `<content>`, is it not? If this is not your intention, kindly post an example of how the output that you want should look like.

Comment: nope I was confused. all good on your part. again, big thank you.

Comment: @Galgu No worries. Good luck!