# appending xml node with subnodes of sam name

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have  key-value pairs: `task_vars = '{"BNS_DT": "20220831","DWH_BD": "dwh_bd=2022-08-31","LAYR_CD": "STG"}'`

with which I would like to generate subnodes `variable`: `tsk_var = ET.fromstring("""<variable><name></name><value></value></variable>""")`

and then append `variables` node in:  `payload = ET.fromstring("""<task-launch><variables></variables><name>{}</name></task-launch>""".format(task_name))`

I loop though the key-values and try to append `variables` node:

```
tsk_vars = json.loads(task_vars)
for name, value in tsk_vars.items():
    for nm in tsk_var.iter('name'):
        nm.text = name
    for vl in tsk_var.iter('value'):
        vl.text = value
    print('to be added')
    print(ET.tostring(tsk_var))
    payload.find('variables').append(tsk_var)
```

When I print out the subnode by which `variables` should be appended I got correct values on each iteration. But in final result I get correct number of subnodes but all are filled with last key value:

```
<task-launch>
  <variables>
    <variable>
        <name>LAYR_CD</name>
        <value>STG</value>
    </variable>
    <variable>
        <name>LAYR_CD</name>
        <value>STG</value>
    </variable>
    <variable>
        <name>LAYR_CD</name>
        <value>STG</value>
    </variable>
 </variables>
```

Please hot do I get correct values for every `variable` subnode?

Comment: later I found this question helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54333130/how-to-insert-xml-python-when-multiple-fields-have-the-same-name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
destination = payload.find('.//variables')

# use f-strings to insert the values into the <variable> children
for name, value in tsk_vars.items():
    new_childs = ET.fromstring(f"""<variable><name>{name}</name><value>{value}</value></variable>""")
    destination.insert(0,new_childs)

#the line below requires python 3.9+
ET.indent(payload, space='  ', level=0)

print(ET.tostring(payload).decode())
```

Output:

```
<task-launch>
  <variables>
    <variable>
      <name>LAYR_CD</name>
      <value>STG</value>
    </variable>
    <variable>
      <name>DWH_BD</name>
      <value>dwh_bd=2022-08-31</value>
    </variable>
    <variable>
      <name>BNS_DT</name>
      <value>20220831</value>
    </variable>
  </variables>
</task-launch>
```